# bash + verify name by regular expression

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, regular-expression

Why does the following regular expression print `valid`, when the name is `hdpworker01`?

```
name=hdpworker01
[[ $name =~ worker[[:digit:]] ]] && echo valid
```

What I try to do is print `valid` only if the name matches `worker[0-999]`.

Example expected results:

- For `name=worker01`: `valid`
- For `name=hdpworker01`: no output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A regular expression is not anchored to the start or end of a string by default.  This is different from e.g. filename globbing patterns.  This means that the expression may match anywhere in the given string.

To have your expression anchored to the start of the string, use

```
^worker[[:digit:]]
```

To additionally anchor it to the end of the string and to allow for one to three digits, use

```
^worker[[:digit:]]{1,3}$
```

If you want to match `worker10` but not `worker01` or `worker003` (no zero-filled numbers), use

```
^worker([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2})$
```

Answer (score 1):

Anchor the regex on both sides.

```
^worker[[:digit:]]$
```

Answer (score 1):

> why the following regular expression print valid , while name is hdpworker01

Why? Because the regex is not **anchored**, i.e. it does not define the start (or end) of the string that is supposed to be matched. The regex `worker` will match if any part of the string being matched is `worker`. It will match `hdpworkeranything` as well as `worker` as many other variations. To match an string that start with `worker` make the regex contain a `^`, like:

```
^worker
```

If you want to match (up to) 3 digits after the word worker, you may use:

```
^worker[0-9]{0,3}$
```

However, it will be wise to capture the number with parenthesis and place the regex inside a variable (using a variable is the present best practice):

```
re='^worker([0-9]{0,3})$'
```

The `$` means that the string should end at that point.
The match will become:

```
[[ $str =~ $re ]] && n=$((10#${BASH_REMATCH[1]}+0)) || n=-1
```

> what I try to do is to print valid only if name is worker[0-999]

And that will allow to check the number `n` range:

```
(( 0 <= n && n <= 999 )) && echo "valid with n=$n"
```